# Issues when moving code from one class into a new class?

Tags: c++, class

I had some decryption code (using `wincrypt.h`) that lived within my `FileReader.cpp` class.  I am trying to segregate the code and push this decryption method into a `MyCrypt.cpp` class.  However, upon moving it I'm stuck with a bunch of errors that I wasn't facing before.  For every `wincrypt.h` or `windows.h` specific command, I am recieving "identifier not found" or "undeclared identifier".

What gives!

More details..

Sample errors:

> error C2065: 'HCRYPTPROV' : undeclared
>   identifier
>
> error C3861: 'CryptDecrypt':
>   identifier not found

I am including windows.h and wincrypt.h, just as I was in FileReader.cpp.

```
#include "MyCrypt.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
```

MyCrypt.h is defined as:

```
#pragma once

class MyCrypt
{
public:
    static char *DecryptMyFile(char *input, char *password, int size, int originalSize) ;

private:
    static const DWORD KEY_LENGTH = 128;
}
```

If I rearrange my include files, I get the following errors instead:

> error C2628: 'MyCrypt' followed by
>   'char' is illegal (did you forget a
>   ';'?)  error C2556: 'MyCrypt
>   *MyCrypt::DecryptMyFile(char *,char *,int,int)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'char
>   *MyCrypt::DecryptMyFile(char *,char *,int,int)

But nowhere in my code does it use this redefinition it speaks of..

Comment: can you post more details?  Like, say, the line it errors out on and the full error you get?

Comment: Does MyCrypt.cpp #include wincrypt.h and windows.h in the same way that FileReader.cpp was?

Comment: Added more details to description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check MyCrypt.h and make sure there's a `;` after the closing brace.  I've seen some fairly strange error messages when I've missed that.  It's missing in the sample you posted.

Comment: That's bitten me a few times too, especially when I go back to C++ after using other languages for a while.  It's one of the first things I check now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget the semicolon after your class declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the code you moved out of FileReader.cpp was either referencing member variables of that class which don't exist in MyCrypt.cpp or methods that were #included in FileReader.cpp that weren't included in MyCrypt.cpp.

Comment: This was my initial impression but it doesn't seem to be the case.  I have updated my description with a few more details.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are now missing some #include's in the new MyCrypt.cpp file, such as windows.h and wincrypt.h, but we need the actual errors to specifically helpful.

Comment: I thought this as well, but I don't believe so while double checking.  I have added more details to my description

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- are you calling methods without referencing the object first (since they were in the old class and now moved, maybe you forgot to call them through a pointer in the new class?)
- you could try shifting the order of the include statements.
- are you using precompiled headers? You could try without to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Going through and trying these...Removing my precompiled header reference yields a compiler error.  "unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header"

Comment: Added the results of rearranging my include statements to the description